# Binding a Repeat Control to either a session or view scope variable

Tags: javascript, xpages, repeat

I have a repeat control which I have bound to a sessionScope variable and it works fine. I am trying to make the control a bit more extensible by dynamically binding it to either a viewScope or a sessionScope variable. I have added a Custom Property to the Control that holds the repeat and have called it scope. The problem is how to bind the repeat to the correct Scoped variable.
On the Repeat control I have selected JavaScript as the binding method and added this code:

```
switch (compositeData.scope){
    case 'ss' :
        return sessionScope.ssCat1
        break;
    case 'vs' :
        return viewScope.vsCat1
        break
}
```

I have checked and in my case compositeData.scope = 'ss' and the sessionScope.ssCat1 contains the correct data.

So am I missing something or is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it not a better way to inject the repeat values in the custom control by a custom parameter
Name it repeat or something else with object as property type.

In your custom control you have

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30"
      var="rowData" style="width:400px" value="#{compositeData.repeat}">
//do what ever you want with a rowData
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: You are probably correct, I stripped my example down to basics and actually the code worked correctly, my problem was actually elsewhere in my page. Should have just stripped it down to begin with. In my real life example I generate several different scoped variable that I use besides in the repeat so using  the scope = 'vs ' or 'ss' actually works OK. If it were a single scoped variable your method is probably better and easier.